# Discrete math proof-verification of divisibility. Case with both truth and a counterexample

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, divisibility

If you need me to expand or write the proof more formally please let me know.

I am confused by the following question, where it seems I have found both a universal value that makes the question true, but then I have also found a counterexample. Where did I go wrong in my proof? Is the statement true or false?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your negation of the statement is not correct.  The original statement is

> $$\forall a \ \exists b\ (3 \mid a+b)$$

Its negation is

> $$\exists a\ \forall b (3 \not\mid a+b)\tag{1}$$

What you showed is

> $$\forall b\ \exists a\ (3 \not\mid a+b)\tag{2}$$

Interchanging those two quantifiers is a big deal.  In (2), $a$ can depend on $b$.  Indeed, this is what you did to show the statement is true.  But in (1), $a$ comes first and $b$ is arbitrary.

Your proof of truth of the original statement is valid.  To make it clear that you are using the quantifiers correctly, you should add words to your proof. “Given $a$, let $b=-a$.  Then $b+a = 0$, and $3 \mid 0$.”  The use of “given” refers to the “for all” quantifier, and the use of “let” refers to “there exists.”

Comment: "Interchanging those two quantifiers is a big deal. In (2), aa can depend on bb. " . But in this case DOES it matter? Because the end of the statement is just an addition statement (a+b), so if you are doing for all A or for all B how does it change anything and why would it matter in this case which quantifier came first?....What I am looking at is the (1-b) that I wrote. Does it not solve your (1), since the A that exists is (1-b) and that (1-b) makes 3 'not divide' A+B for all B?

Comment: @SajSeesSound: The "end" of the statement matters less than the beginning.  Try with these two: "For all $y>0$ there exists an $x>0$ such that $y=x^2$." and "There exists an $x>0$ such that for all $y>0$, $y=x^2$." Only one of those is true.

Comment: Yeah but those are seperated by an equal sign. If it was x+y, then x+y and y+x are the same thing... Still dont get it... I am trying to use your logic here, but I dont see why (2) is not proving the statement even though it makes sense to write: Given $b$ let $a=1-b$ Then $3 | 1-b+b=1$

Comment: I think I may have grasped it. Please let me know if the following is correct. SO in your $(2)$ What I was basically doing was giving a value to $a ->$ $(a=1-b)$ before I stated $for all b$. So the proof I was writing was not working or being written for $a+b$ it was in fact working/being written for $1-b+b$. Is that right?

Comment: @SajSeesSound When you say "let $a=1-b$", then $a$ depends on $b$.  This means $a$ can't come before $b$ as a quantified variable.  The fact that the statement *starts* with $\exists a$ means that $a$ must be a constant.

Comment: ALthough your (1) is false, could you start writing the beginning of a proof for it so that I can find out which components you would give values to for quantifiers in that specific order and for that specific statement... for calrity.

Comment: @SajSeesSound: "Let $a=1$.  Then for any given $b$, $3$ does not divide $1+b$."  (not true, of course; it fails for $b=2$ or $b=-1$ as you show)